# Как использовать общий MediaPlayer для разных кнопок и мелодий?

Tags: java, android

Не могу нигде найти статью об этом, думаю может вы поможете.
Итак, есть 4 кнопки в приложении и каждая из них воспроизводит мелодию при нажатии, вопрос в том, как сделать, что бы при нажатии на 2-4 кнопки сразу, издавался звук который привязан к последней кнопки на которую нажали. Сейчас при нажатии на 2 и более кнопок играют все мелодии одновременно. Использовал класс MediaPlayer. Спасибо за внимание.

```
MediaPlayer mysound1;
MediaPlayer mysound2;
MediaPlayer mysound3;
MediaPlayer mysound4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
}

public void sound1 (View view) {
    mysound1.start();
}

public void sound2 (View view) {
    mysound2.start();
}

public void sound3 (View view) {
    mysound3.start();
}

public void sound4 (View view) {
    mysound4.start();
}
```

Comment: Покажите код. А так надо при нажатии на кнопку просто остановить текущую воспроизводимую мелодию. Для этого нужна ссылка на общий для всех кнопок MediaPlayer. У вас же он, наверное, для каждой кнопки свой отдельный создаётся. Но без кода вашего можно только гадать. А под такую конкретную и узкую задачу вы статей не найдёте - никому и в голову не придёт их писать.

Comment: mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
        mysound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
        mysound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
        mysound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);

        }

public void sound1 (View view) {
        mysound1.start();

        }

public void sound2 (View view) {
        mysound2.start();
        }

public void sound3 (View view) {
        mysound3.start();
        }

public void sound4 (View view) {
        mysound4.start();
        }
        }`
@ЮрийСПб

Comment: Ад какой! Создайте MediaPlayer один раз и используйте его для воспроизведения разных звуков. Впрочем, звук у вас один, на сколько я вижу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мы можем перейти в какой-то лайв чат? Звук не один и тот же это тест. Я начал буквально меньше недели изучать синтаксис джавы, перешел с верстки (верстал из псд) и по этому с джавой никогда дела не имел. Я бы не прочь перейти в лайв чат и обсудить эту тематику, что бы не ждать долго ответа, если вас не затруднит.

Comment: @bytes, мне в чатах общаться религия не позволяет (и цель существования сайта) - только вопрос-ответ, только хардкор. И не выкладывайте код в комменты - выкладывайте в вопрос через правку оного

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Хорошо, тогда сейчас выложу код в вопрос. Суть такого, что я хочу сделать приложение, которое имеет 4 кнопки. И при нажатии на каждую кнопку, будет разный звук. Суть проблемы в том, что я не знаю как сделать, что бы при нажатии на следующую кнопку, предыдущий звук останавливался и начинался новый.

Comment: Вам стоит сначала хорошо изучать основы самого языка и принципов программирования на нём, а уж потом браться за предметную область.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне легче усваивать на практике.

Comment: Ребята, ну помогите решить эту проблемку.

Comment: @bytes, мы бы и рады, но вот лично я на работе сейчас и отвлечься не могу. Так-то решение в моём первом комменте есть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ Извиняюсь, за то что у вас отнимаю рабочее время. Мне не надо делать отдельную кнопку STOP, мне надо сделать так, что бы при нажатии на другую кнопку, звук с первой кнопки прекратил воспроизводится и началось воспроизведение звука с другой кнопки, но к сожалению я так и не понял, как я могу это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Правильным решением было бы использование одного экземпляра медиа плеера с асинхронной загрузкой мелодии. Но тут может возникнуть проблема с откликом - после нажатия надо будет подождать пока мелодия загрузится.

Т.е., положим, при старте активити надо запустить загрузку всех методий и дезактивировать кнопки до загрузки всех мелодий. После чего их активировать.
Если загружать их так как вы сейчас делаете, то основной поток будет заморожен. И если мелодии тяжёлые и/или их много то приложение упадёт по ANR.

Так что вот вам решение в лоб. Оно неправильное, т.к. решает лишь локально проблему для вашего кода. Поместите все экземпляры плеера в список и при воспроизведении следующего трека - остановите все остальные:

```
MediaPlayer mysound1;
MediaPlayer mysound2;
MediaPlayer mysound3;
MediaPlayer mysound4;

private List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mysound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    mysound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sasa);
    players.add(mysound1);
    players.add(mysound2);
    players.add(mysound3);
    players.add(mysound4);
}

public void sound1 (View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound1.start();
}

public void sound2 (View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound2.start();
}

public void sound3 (View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound3.start();
}

public void sound4 (View view) {
    stopAll();
    mysound4.start();
}

private void stopAll(){
    for(MediaPlayer player : players) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Работоспособность не гарантирована - может потребоваться перезагрузка мелодии в плеер после его остановки.

Comment: благодарю, но с кодом возникли проблемы, последние строки начиная с private void stopAll(){

Comment: @bytes, вы же не ожидаете что я смогу с 10-го хотя бы раза угадать что именно за проблема?..

Comment: так ведь проблема с методом StopAll вроде как.

Comment: @bytes, с ним нет проблем. Вы меня обманываете. Если нет - объясните что же там не так. Вы же поймёте аналогию про бабушку у которой разлогинился скайп и она говорит что процессор не работает?

Comment: Аналогию понял, так как в начинке Пк и По понимаю, а вот в Js - нет. 
Спасибо и на этом.

Comment: @bytes, вам сложно сказать что за проблема? У вас не компилируется (приложение не запускается, код выделен красным подчёркиванием)? Компилируется, запускается, но падает? Если да то где? С какой ошибкой? На какой строке? Что в логах? Без этой информации вам никак же не помочь. Вы же не ожидаете что я могу мысли читать? 0_о

Comment: не компилировалось. Сам решил проблему. Проблема была в private List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();
Изменил на  private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>(); и скомпилировал apk.

Comment: @bytes, скорее всего вам надо было просто импортировать интерфейс лист (Alt+Enter->Import). Если в итоге оно у вас работает - вы можете отметить ответ "верным" (галочка слева от тела ответа)